# How to recover default boost installation on ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

I was trying to compile boost 1.62 from source on ubuntu 12.04 where the default version is 1.48. During the course of trying everything, I removed boost from /usr/include/boost and libboost* from /usr/lib using the following commands

- sudo rm -r /usr/include/boost
- sudo rm -r /usr/include/libboost*

I have realized that now I need the default version (1.48) for my program to work. But when I use the following command

> sudo apt-get install libboost-dev-all

it seems to install the libboost, but I am not able to see any boost directory in /usr/include. Moreover, I tried compiling a few programs with cmake and it also doesn't seem to find any boost library on the system.

Is it not possible to reinstall libboost if the libraries and headers have been removed manually ?

Answer (score 0):

from the ubuntu forums :

> choices:
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall mypackage
>
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure mypackage
>
> ( or if the other solutions have failed:
>
> sudo apt-get purge mypackage && sudo apt-get install mypackage
>
> and logout/in )

give it a shot !

also if you don't see any librarie after installing one you can run :

```
sudo ldconfig
```

The above command will make ld (the dynamic libraries loader) aware of the new libraries.

Comment: thanks. Seems header and lib files are back. But cmake cannot still find BOOST_ROOT. is there a way to reset that ?

Comment: Have you run the ldconfig command ? alo have you written the cmake file that finds BOOST yourself ?

Comment: yes, cmake still gives error:   common is required but boost was not found

Comment: Also, I have checked that all libraries are not back. libboost_thread etc are yet to be recovered

Comment: then have you try purgin the package and reinstalling it ?

Comment: If the package manager doesn't help you then i would recommand you remove it completely and do a manual compilation / installation .